# save profile image inside app using the built in camera

Tags: swift, xcode, swift3

I have an app that contains a profile of the user.
In the profile editing, he has an option to take a photo of himself, then that photo should be saved in his details and be presented in certain places in the app.

Is there a way to internally save an image (not in his phone's photo gallery, but inside the app itself, so he cannot delete the photo through the phone), and then fetch that image every time I need it?

I understand I cannot use CoreData to save images, so I am wondering if there is an easier way to get it done efficiently.
Or must I do that in a server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> not in his phone's photo gallery, but inside the app itself

You can't store anything at runtime "inside the app itself". But the app has a *sandbox*, a folder area belonging to you alone, where you can store any file you like — in the Documents folder or the Application Support folder, for example. So why not just use that?

Comment: This is the exact thing i am looking for, thanks for pointing it out, will research in that direction

Comment: Sure, here's some example code: https://github.com/mattneub/Programming-iOS-Book-Examples/blob/master/bk2ch23p798basicFileOperations/ch36p1053basicFileOperations/ViewController.swift